# how to Redirect a path which is typed in addressbar after successful login in spring security mvc

Tags: spring-security

how to Redirect a page which is typed in addressbar after successful login in spring security mvc.bydefault im hardcoded default target url in my security.xml file

Answer (score 0):

[`SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccesshandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) has a [`userReferer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.html#setUseReferer%28boolean%29) property.

You can create an instance of this and use it in your authentication filter. The namespace [`form-login`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-form-login) element has an `authentication-success-handler-ref` option.